# Proving Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

How do I show that the inner product;

<A$\vec{u}$,$\vec{v}$> = <$\vec{u}$,A$^T$$\vec{v}$>

Comment: Think about how inner product $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle$ of two vectors is related to transposes.

Comment: I think you misstated the problem, because as it is written the statement is false; take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, u = (1, 1), v = (2, 1)$ for example. Did you mean $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A^T v \rangle$ ?

Comment: oh my god yeah how dumb of me. Yeah how do i prove that? i have made the edit in my post. This was given as a guide to prove that a rotation matrice is orthogonal

Comment: Just a remark: when it comes to infinite dimensional vector spaces, this property defines what a "transpose" (more commonly referred to as the "adjoint") is. In other words, the adjoint of an operator $A$ is the operator $A^\dagger$ such that
$$\langle A u, v \rangle = \langle u, A^\dagger v \rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that the inner product $\langle u, v \rangle$ can be written as $u^Tv$, we have

$$\langle Au, v \rangle = (Au)^Tv = (u^TA^T)v = u^T(A^Tv) = \langle u, A^Tv \rangle$$.